# Order not save using sagepay payment gateway in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, opayo

I am working on magento 1.7 version. 
When I placed a order using sagepay payment gateway it could not save the order in the back-end of magento.

In sagepay log it shows like below:-

**DEBUG: Could not save order: Please check shipping address information. Please enter the first name. Please enter the last name. Please enter the street. Please enter the city. Please enter the telephone number. Please enter the zip/postal code.**

**[Status] => OK**

**[StatusDetail] => 0000 : The Authorisation was Successful.**

**[AVSCV2] => ALL MATCH**

**[AddressResult] => MATCHED**

**[PostCodeResult] => MATCHED**

**[CV2Result] => MATCHED**

**[GiftAid] => 0**

**[3DSecureStatus] => NOTCHECKED**

**[fail_status] => An error occurred: Please check shipping address information. Please enter the first name. Please enter the last name. Please enter the street. Please enter the city. Please enter the telephone number. Please enter the zip/postal code.**

Billing and shipping address filled properly.

It is showing that payment is deducted from customer account and showing in merchant account but neither order placed in magento admin nor email sent to customer.

What would be the reason behind this? I am using one step checkout of Idev http://www.onestepcheckout.com/.

Please provide the solution regarding this.

Comment: can you please place order with default magento checkout means one page checkout to conform if problem with IWD onepage or not

Comment: This happens only with two orders not for all.

Comment: This is not  IWD onepage this is Idev (http://www.onestepcheckout.com/). Updated in question

Comment: Mine solved after a module upgrade (ebzmarts sagepay)

Answer (score 0):

The message would suggest that some fields in the one step checkout process are possibly missing, have you removed fields?

If not it may be that the fields have been changed around?

Finally if the 2 above are fine, have a look at the configuration for what I assume is the SagePay extension eBizmarts configuration.

What is 'Payment Action' set to? What is 'Halt order save' (this is usually set to 'no') set to?

Comment: 'Halt order save' is set to 'NO'.